# changed password but still can't access my account

Tags: ipod

My original computer with my itunes account crashed and burned. I am trying to make sense of the account on my new computer. I was able to buy musice and movies but now I can't do anything. I changed my password but I keep getting a message that says my password is incorrect. its not incorrect. Anybody have any ideas how to fix that. I am totally frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/

Try signing in there. If it works, your Apple ID (and therefore iTunes account) are all working fine and there's an issue with your install of iTunes. If not, you can reset the password from there and hopefully it'll help you get it working on your iTunes.